# How can I get newman's json report directly in a node program?

Tags: node.js, newman

I find `newman`'s documents only describe about outputting report to CLI or files. Is there a way to get the report json directly when I use the `newman` library in node.js?

```
    newman.run({
        collection: new Collection(collection),
        reporter: ['json'] // Can I insert a callback function receiving json report here?
    }, err => {
        // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the callback function.

`summary` in `callback (err, summary)` is what I need.